# MonologBundle FingerCrossedHandler: how to configure excluded_404s

Tags: symfony, monolog

I'm working on a Symfony 2.8.6 application and I tried to configure my Monolog as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog_regex_based_excludes.html) and [here](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/issues/106).
This is my Monolog config (bundle version 2.11.1):

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main_critical:
            type:           fingers_crossed
            action_level:   error
            handler:        grouped
            channels:       ["!doctrine", "!event", "!php"]
            excluded_404s:
                - ^/
        grouped:
            type:           group
            members:        [streamed, crash, buffered]
        streamed:
            type:           rotating_file
            max_files:      10
            path:           "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level:          notice
        crash:
            type:           rotating_file
            max_files:      10
            path:           "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.critical.log"
            level:          critical
        buffered:
            type:           buffer
            handler:        swift
        swift:
            type:           swift_mailer
            from_email:     noreply@xxxxxxx.com
            to_email:       user@xxxxx.com
            subject:        "[App] - Errore %kernel.environment%"
            level:          error
```

Monolog logs every 404 error, also missing assets like css and js.
How can avoid this?
Where I'm wrong?

Maybe the problem is related with my ExceptionListener?

```
     /**
     * @param GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {   
        //The logger object is my logger
        $this->logger->log($event->getException(), $event->getRequest());
        if (!$event->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return;
        }
        $event->setResponse(new JsonResponse('message' => 'Ops. Houston we have a problem.'));
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post how I resolved. The problem isn't related with Monolog, but with my logger service.

Because I wrapped how to log exceptions, before I didn't pass the exception when I call

```
$logger->error('message error');
```

So when Monolog tries to enable the NotFoundActivationStrategy (file is located in `/vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/NotFoundActivationStrategy.php`), this check fails:

```
public function isHandlerActivated(array $record)
{
    $isActivated = parent::isHandlerActivated($record);
    if (
        $isActivated
        && $this->request
        && isset($record['context']['exception'])
        && $record['context']['exception'] instanceof HttpException
        && $record['context']['exception']->getStatusCode() == 404
     ) {
        //blacklist is the pattern that you can set on config.yml at excluded_404s node
        return !preg_match($this->blacklist, $this->request->getPathInfo());
     }

     return $isActivated;
 }
```

So I resolved with

```
$this->logger->error('message', array('exception' => $exception));
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter errors in onKernelException method. See example below:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Listener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class AppExceptionListener
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct($logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();

        if(!$exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
        {
            $this->logger->info('Error');
        }
    }

}
```