# Symfony/Monolog: how to customize the format of logs about 404 not found exceptions

Tags: php, symfony, logging, http-status-code-404, monolog

Monolog offers a way to [exclude 404 errors from the log](http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/monolog_regex_based_excludes.html), but what if I want to customize them instead of totally suppressing them?

So showing something different than:

> [2016-12-12 10:41:01] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /non-existing-route"" at /myproject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 125 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /non-existing-route\" at /myproject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:125, Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /myproject/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php:1181)"} []

Comment: Do you mean the way it is logged in log file?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're talking about the log life in app/logs directory. If so, I would do it this way which is pretty straight forward.

1. Create a custom logger and associated log formatter. Example: [Creating a custom monolog logger and formatter in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/6f30/creating-a-custom-monolog-logger-and-formatter-in-symfony)
2. I would then catch `NotFoundHttpException` exception in a custom event listener (Example: [Triggering redirect in event listener with onKernelException when 404 NotFoundHttpException occurs](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/xtjc/triggering-redirect-in-event-listener-with-on-kernel-exception-when-404-not-found-http-exception-occurs)) and log it with my custom logger that I created in step 1.

Note: Your custom logger is injected in controller in step 1 above. In your case, inject it to your event listener.

Comment: thanks @BentCoder I'm working on it, but now I'm getting both the new custom log and the old default one. How can I suppress the old one?

Comment: I never tried it but surely it should be easy so check this [How to Configure Monolog to Exclude 404 Errors from the Log](http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/monolog_regex_based_excludes.html) or just [search for it](https://www.google.com.tr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=symfony%20prevent%20logging%20404).

Comment: yes that is what I'm trying but apparently it does not work, however I will check further, thanks

Comment: Check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299284/monologbundle-fingercrossedhandler-how-to-configure-excluded-404s

Comment: @BentCoder, the solution you've offered works only for `fingers_crossed`.

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution is to use log processor.

The detailed documentation is at [How to Add extra Data to Log Messages via a Processor](http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/processors.html)

Then inside the process or detect the `NotFoundHttpException`  and replace it with human-readable message.